# I am getting Bad Credentials Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

//controller

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

    authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
            .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

    final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
}

private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
    } catch (DisabledException e) {
        throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
    }
}
```

@PostMapping("/register") public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDTO user) throws Exception { return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetailsService.save(user)); }

//service

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
            new ArrayList<>());
}
```

public User save(UserDTO user) {
User newUser = new User(); newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername()); newUser.setEmail(user.getEmail()); newUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword())); return service.storeUser(newUser);
}

//Websecurity configuration file

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
    // user for matching credentials
    // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
    auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}



@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    // We don't need CSRF for this example
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            // dont authenticate this particular request
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register").permitAll().
            // all other requests need to be authenticated
                    anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
            // store user's state.
                    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

//jwtrequestfilter

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    String username = null;
    String jwtToken = null;
    // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
    // only the Token
    if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
        }
    } else {
        logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
    }

    // Once we get the token validate it.
    if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

        UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
        // authentication
        if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
            // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
            // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code little more and post the stacktrace also.

Comment: Please post your API to signup a user as well.

Comment: You can edit your question.  Can you put the extra code you just gave us into the question rather than in comments?

Comment: I got it when I changed my database

Comment: how to remove jwt token